# How can I edit the content of .properties file?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler, jenkins-cli

I am using Jenkins server with perforce. My build get stored in a local repo path in ".zip" format which contains all the file including (say) *abc.properties*. This file contains data:

```
#Thu Jun 09 12:13:14 MSD 2011
BuildType=dev
FrameworkBuild=200
ProductVersion=4.40.00
SoftwareFeatureID=34670101
BuildNumber=0
FrameworkVersion=2.47.00
```

In this *abc.properties* file `BuildNumber = 0` is a default value(set in perforce). My old build system updates the `BuildNumber` value with current build number in the zip file.

How can I achieve the same in Jenkins.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) for this, jenkins is not a build tool.

Comment: Can I achieve this through "Execute Windows Batch File" in build environment. If it so. How? Please help

Answer (score 10):

Add a post build step.  This assumes you are running Unix and have sed on the path.

```
sed -i -e '/BuildNumber =/ s/= .*/= "$BUILD_NUMBER";/' abc.properties
```

Also, I could not disagree more with the selected answer.  Jenkins is a build tool.

> Jenkins focuses on the following two jobs: Building/testing software
>   projects continuously
>   https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what kind of build do you run. If you have a maven or ant project, these two frameworks will update the property file if you ask them to.

Comment: My project is a freestyle project. Is maven configurable with it??